# How to call a .NET class from a Java class in Mono from Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have implemented a Java activity that displays a Google map view, and would like to use an existing .NET framework class to that returns locations, from a web service, to display on the map. Is this possible or should I just consume the web service in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this implementing [ACW](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Architecture/Android_Callable_Wrappers),but i think that it is to difficult and better to use some android framework for this purpose.

Also why you can't implement this activity using managed code?

Comment: The Google Maps API is not part of Mono for Android 1 and can only be included via .jar file. See the *How it works* section of https://github.com/mono/monodroid-samples/tree/master/GoogleMaps.

Comment: I know that. Then i dont understand what is your problem? You can create managed Activity with google map view via JNIEnv, and use existing .net framework for locations.

Comment: My problem is that I didn't know that until just now.

Comment: I worked around this issue by pre-loading the locations. By the time got around to resolving this issue Mono for Android supported Google Maps API. I never did try the JNIEnv solution.