# How to call Mono for Android class from within Android application?

Tags: c#, java, android, interop, xamarin.android

I have created a fairly simple Activity in Mono for Android project:

```
[Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    private string value = "intitial";

    [Export]
    public string GetString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    [Export]
    public void SetString(string newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
}
```

The activity should only serve as a proof-of-concept, hence its simplicity. Now, I'd like to be able to call the method GetString() from the "normal", Java-based Android application.

In [Xamarin's docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Java_Integration), I've read about Java to Managed interop, which seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. If I understand it correctly, when Mono for Android app compiles, it generates Java classes that are referred to as Android Callable Wrappers (ACW). I should be then able to call methods on these ACWs from Java-based Android application.

The question is, how exactly do I reference compiled Mono for Android application (the *apk* file) from the Java-based Android app?

This is where I'm now stuck and was unable to find any concrete examples. There are similar questions here on SO ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279012/how-to-call-a-net-class-from-a-java-class-in-mono-from-android) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467469/monodroid-interop-betwen-java-and-c-sharp)) and some blogposts, but they just boil down to "use ACWs". **But how exactly?** Maybe I am missing something obvious here, being no Android guy.

What I've tried is to dynamically load the *dex* file that I yanked from my Mono for Android *apk*. I've simply put it on the storage card and then tried to use `DexClassLoader` from Java-based Android app to load it (I've followed this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html)). The ACW class was found, but when I tried to create its instance, I got the following error:

> No implementation found for native Lmno/android/Runtime;.register (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)

I suppose that I have to somehow include Mono for Android runtime to the Java-based app, but I have no idea how.

**EDIT:**
This is the code I am trying to load the *dex* with:

```
DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
    optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
    null,
    getClassLoader());

try {
    Class<?> classActivity1 = cl.loadClass("androidapplication1.Activity1");

    // the following line throws the exception
    Object a = classActivity1.newInstance();

    Method getStringMethod = classActivity1.getMethod("GetString");
    Object result = getStringMethod.invoke(angel);

    result = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I am now reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814478/using-c-sharp-library-with-mono-for-android-from-java-code) that it should be possible to directly start activities written in Mono for Android from Java. It is still not clear to me how to reference the Mono for Android from Java and Googling yields no relevant hits. Really stumped now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do, this isn't really possible. As the error message you got implies, an Activity within a Mono for Android application relies on the Mono runtime in order to function properly. The callable wrapper isn't useful on its own in this case, since it's just a thin Java wrapper class that calls into the Mono runtime. You can actually see the generated callable wrappers yourself if you look in the obj/Debug/android/src folder after you build your project. For example:

```
package androidapplication9;


public class Activity1
    extends android.app.Activity
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer
{
    static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "n_onCreate:(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V:GetOnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_Handler\n" +
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("AndroidApplication9.Activity1, AndroidApplication9, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", Activity1.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public Activity1 ()
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == Activity1.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("AndroidApplication9.Activity1, AndroidApplication9, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }


    public void onCreate (android.os.Bundle p0)
    {
        n_onCreate (p0);
    }

    private native void n_onCreate (android.os.Bundle p0);

    java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

That said, due to the way Android works, you could have a Java application start an activity that is defined in a Mono for Android application in the same way you'd start an external Java activity. This relies on both applications being installed, of course, but would result in the Mono for Android application and Mono runtime actually starting up to run that activity.

**Edit**

Updating to answer the questions you posed in your comment. The [`ExportAttribute`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Java.Interop.ExportAttribute) basically just gives you some more control in how the ACW gets generated, allowing you to specify that a particular method or field should be present in the ACW and what name it should have. This can be useful when you want to use things like an android:onClick attribute in a layout, for example, where by default the ACW wouldn't contain the method you want to reference.

You can't get much use out of an ACW outside of the context of a Mono for Android application since the Mono runtime wouldn't be present. Code written in C# is executed on top of the Mono runtime, and not translated into Java behind the scenes during compilation or anything like that. At runtime there are then two runtimes going side by side, Dalvik (Android's runtime) and Mono, and the callable wrappers are there to allow the two to communicate back and forth. Because of that, even a Mono for Android class library would still depend on the Mono runtime, so you cannot use it independently of that runtime.

This diagram shows what the architecture looks like, and how the runtimes relate to each other:

[image: Mono for Android architecture]

Hope this helps clear things up!

Comment: Thank you _very_ much for your answer, finally something to work with! What are you saying makes a lot of sense, but what’s then a purpose of those Xamarin docs linked in my question? When would I use ACWs and `Export` attribute? And perhaps most importantly, is there _any_ way whatsoever to make Java app „talk“ to Mono for Android class without having to install two separate apps – i.e.something like having a Mono for Android library and just referencing it from the Java app? I would be really grateful if you could clear this up a bit for me.